# How's Liquidity Pool ID obtained from?

Tags: web3js, uniswap, nodejs, liquidity-provider, sushiswap

When programming Yield Farming, particularly in JS, `MasterChefV3` requires an ID of liquidity pool, in order to make a `deposit(...)` into it.

Where or how does one get a liquidity pool ID? it's not returned by `router2.addLiquidity(...)` on a previous step, is it? Then how or where is it obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Pool ID (or also commonly called pid) are incremented every time a pool is added by the Masterchef contract owner.

[image: Sushiswap MasterChefV2]

Here, the *pid* is created by the `.push` method in the `poolInfo` array.
So essentially, the pid is the index of the `poolInfo` array.

The `router2.addLiquidity(...)` has no relation with the Masterchef contract, which usually needs Liquidity tokens (LP) in order to deposit them in the contract and earn rewards.

Comment: and? How or where will I get `pool_id` in order to be able to pass it to `MasterChef.deposit(...)`?

Comment: You need to check in all poolId array elements in order to find the correct pool to deposit to

Comment: when traversing elements in `[poolInfo]`, by what criteria can I recognise the correct pool?

Comment: Well, commonly the poolToken

Comment: What's `poolToken`?